# Java - Upper Case Text

Tags: java, string

I am trying to get the first character of a string to convert into an upper case. How is this possible?

For example;

```
String c = "hi steve, how are you doing?";
```

I want the 'h' of 'hi' capitalized. How do I do that using code?
Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Using code, you use code. Look at the `String` javadoc.

Comment: Just first character of entire string? Or for each word?

Comment: You can use `substring` and `toUpperCase` methods from String class. You can also use `Character` class for this task.

Comment: `System.out.println("Hi steve, how are you doing?");`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You will find it's not a "Do my homework for me" service.

Comment: @BrianRoach I am asking an actual question here. I never learned how to convert the first character of a string capitalized, I couldn't find it anywhere- so that's why I am here now.

Comment: In StackOverflow you need to show that you have done some effort by yourself. "What have you tried?" is a popular reply to these kind of questions -- see http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/.

Comment: Be sure to visit again for the second character... and especially the third one, cause that one's much trickier.

Comment: @user3368814 you're being ridiculed because you asked an extremely basic question you could certainly find the answer to with more effort. Sorry, StackOverflow doesn't look kindly on that. Hence the downvotes.

Answer (score 1):

```
c = Character.toUpperCase(c.charAt(0))+c.substring(1);
```

Comment: breaks on length 0 and 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String`'s [`charAt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29) method to get the first character and the `Character` [`toUpperCase`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toUpperCase%28char%29) method to convert it to upper case. Then use the [`substring`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29) method to get everything after the first character.

```
String c = "hi steve, how are you doing?";
c = Character.toUpperCase(c.charAt(0)) + c.substring(1);
System.out.println(c);
```

Comment: +1 for sympathy and sullying yourself

Answer (score 0):

Use of stringbuilder creates less strings:

```
StringBuilder s1 = new StringBuilder("hi steve");
s1.replace(0, s1.length(), s1.toString().toLowerCase());
s1.setCharAt(0, Character.toTitleCase(s1.charAt(0)));
```